# PH or stored procedure (function)

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing some functions for a customer. The base is a MySQL database with polygons for large districts and small polygons for small districts.

I have written a PHP function that retrieves information if a small district has any common area with any large districts. It's about 100 lines of PHP code and it works fine. It is based on several arrays containing coordinates for the large areas and one array containing the small area.

This is part of a larger project that my customer is developing. He believes that the code could be written as a Stored Procedure in MySQL and that this would be more efficient.

I am not familiar with stored procedures but the little I have read it seems they are really designed for retrieving data from the database, not for making computations on arrays of data and I doubt that there really are any performance gains. And the code seems to be more complex/messy by embedding it in SQL queries.

I would like to get the opinion from someone with experience from stored procedures and/or functions.

Comment: 1 - you need to post your code, 2 - a stored procedure is just your sql stored on the server and instead of sending the whole query you are sending variables think of it as a function, 3 - mysql has geometry functions are you using these ?

Comment: To clarify. A stored procedure is basically for storing complex queries and it returns data from the database. It is not really designed for doing computations on data. Right? I have not been using mysql geometry functions. I will look into that. My php code started its life outside of MySQL

Comment: Just paste the code in here???   200 lines including comments

Comment: The code is way to large to publish here, almost 200 lines including comments. I have temporarily posted it on my blog "Ingvar i Las Palmas" under the heading "Code!!"     ingvare.wordpress.com/

Comment: I got an answer from the MySQL forum where I also posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also posted on the MySQL forum and I got an answer

1 Up to version 5.7 at least, MySQL sprocs do not generally improve performance

2 MySQL has no arrays, you'd have to use pseudoarray strings or memory tables

3 There's not a good sproc debugger

To me, it sounds like a nightmare sproc